# norm of the logarithm of a positive element in $C^*$-algebra

Tags: normed-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $a$ is an positive invertibel elment in a unital $C^*$-algebra.Why is the norm of $log(a)$ equal to max$\{log\|c\|,log\|c^{-1}\|\}$.The norm of $log(a)$ shoud be equal to spectral radius $r(log(a))$ of $log(a)$,but how to show that $r(log(a))=max\{log\|c\|,log\|c^{-1}\|\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spectrum of $\log a$ is 
$$
\sigma(\log a)=\{\log\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma(a)\}.
$$
So, as the norm of a selfadjoint element is the maximum of the absolute value of the elements of the spectrum, 
$$
\|\log a\|=\max\{|\log\lambda|:\ \lambda\in\sigma(a)\}.
$$
When $0<\lambda<1$, you have 
$$
|\log\lambda|=-\log\lambda=\log\lambda^{-1}. 
$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\|\log a\|&=\max\left\{ \{\log\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma(a)\cap[1,\infty)\} \cup \{\log\lambda^{-1}:\ \lambda\in\sigma(a)\cap(0,1)\}\right\}\\
&=\max\left\{ \{\log\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma(a)\cap[1,\infty)\} \cup \{\log\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma(a^{-1})\cap(1,\infty)\}\right\}\\
&=\max\left\{ \{\log\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma(a)\} \cup \{\log\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma(a^{-1})\}\right\}\\
&=\max\{\log\|a\|,\log\|a^{-1}\|\}.
\end{align}